# problems with code generated by SOAP2ObjC

Tags: objective-c, wsdl

I have some problems with WSDL2ObjC.
I generated code from a wsdl file but there seems to be some methods not correct:

```
- (void)getInstallationInfoXMLAsyncUsing delegate:(id<ILIASSoapWebserviceBindingResponseDelegate>)responseDelegate;
```

and

```
    - (void)dealloc

{
    if(sid != nil) [sid release];
    if(role_type != nil) [role_type release];
    if(id != nil) [id release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I changed the first sample to

```
- (void)getInstallationInfoXMLAsyncUsingDelegate:(id<ILIASSoapWebserviceBindingResponseDelegate>)responseDelegate;
```

but i am not sure how to handle

```
if(id != nil) [id release];
```

> file://.../SOAP/ILIASSoapWebservice.m: error: Semantic Issue: Receiver type 'id' is not an Objective-C class

thx in advance,
OmidH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `id` as a variable name but `id` is reserved as a Keyword which refers to an Objective C type. You need to find all instances of `id` used as a variable name and change it to another variable name of your choosing